# how to add jquery in react-static?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to port a typical website made with bootstrap to react-static.

How should I go about jquery into the project?

Importing to app.js does not work, I get `jQuery is not defined`

And other scripts that works fine in normal plain HTML website , here it shows a lot of errors and warnings .
Is there any other way of importing external js in react project ?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Please [edit] your question and describe exactly what you're doing what you expect ti happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: If I import jquary in app js , and run the project.  In the console it shows , "jQuery is not defined"

Comment: use provide plugin

Comment: Made your input a bit easier to read, but I agree with the comments: "does not work" is not a working problem description. Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can use jQuery in ReactJs. Here I will tell how we can use it using npm.

step 1: Go to your project folder where the package.json file is present via user terminal using the cd command.

step 2: write the following command to install jquery using npm: npm install jquery --save

step 3: Now, import "$" from jquery into your jsx file where you need to use.

Example:

write the below in index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery'


//   react code here


$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```